# Remove iptables rules from recovery system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, iptables

I have a remote dedicated server and accidentally added some iptables rules that killed network access. I am only able to access SSH in recovery mode, which gives me access to the filesystem.

I can't use the iptables CLI to remove these rules from recovery mode, so how could I manually remove these (or all) rules with only filesystem access?

Could I prevent iptables from running on the next boot so I could then use the CLI to remove the rules?

Comment: what flavor of Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone else had the issue and response on serverfault. Link here https://serverfault.com/a/561500/261910

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.